# Having trouble with "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties" error

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-structs

Having trouble resolving this error "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties"

Here is the code that prompted the error,

```
import SwiftUI

struct TaskEditView: View
{
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @EnvironmentObject var dateHolder: DateHolder
    @ObservedObject var notificationManager: NotificationManager
    
    @State var selectedTaskItem: TaskItem?
    @State var name: String
    @State var desc: String
    @State var dueDate: Date
    @State var scheduleTime: Bool
    
    init(passedTaskItem: TaskItem?, initialDate: Date)
    {
        if let taskItem = passedTaskItem
        {
            _selectedTaskItem = State(initialValue: taskItem)
            _name = State(initialValue: taskItem.name ?? "")
            _desc = State(initialValue: taskItem.desc ?? "")
            _dueDate = State(initialValue: taskItem.dueDate ?? initialDate)
            _scheduleTime = State(initialValue: taskItem.scheduleTime)
        }
        else
        {
            
            _name = State(initialValue: "")
            _desc = State(initialValue: "")
            _dueDate = State(initialValue: initialDate)
            _scheduleTime = State(initialValue: false)
        }
    } //error appears right here 
    
    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView{
            
        Form
        {
            Section(header: Text("ToDo"))
            {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                TextField("Description", text: $desc)
            }
           
            Section(header: Text("Deadline"))
            {
                Toggle("Schedule Time", isOn: $scheduleTime)
                DatePicker("Date", selection: $dueDate, displayedComponents: displayedComps())
            }
            
            if selectedTaskItem?.isCompleted() ?? false
            {
                Section(header: Text("Completed"))
                {
                    Text(selectedTaskItem?.completedDate?.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .shortened) ?? "")
                }
            }
            
            Section()
            {
                Button("Save", action: saveAction)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Create New ToDo ")
           
            }
        }
    }
    
    func displayedComps() -> DatePickerComponents
    {
        return scheduleTime ? [.hourAndMinute, .date] : [.date]
    }
    
    func saveAction()
    {
        withAnimation
        {
            if selectedTaskItem == nil
            {
                selectedTaskItem = TaskItem(context: viewContext)
            }
        
            selectedTaskItem?.created = Date()
            selectedTaskItem?.name = name
            selectedTaskItem?.desc = desc
            selectedTaskItem?.dueDate = dueDate
            selectedTaskItem?.scheduleTime = scheduleTime
            
            dateHolder.saveContext(viewContext)
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            
        }
        
        let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: dueDate)
        guard let hour = dateComponents.hour, let minute = dateComponents.minute else { return }
        notificationManager.createLocalNotification(title: name, hour: hour, min: minute) { error in
                if error == nil {}
        }
        
    }
}


struct TaskEditView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TaskEditView(passedTaskItem: TaskItem(), initialDate: Date())
    }
}
```

I looked online and it said that I have to initialize all my proporties but im unsure how to do that for the

```
_selectedTaskItem
```

in the else statement.

Im very new to coding and much help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps off topic but selectedTaskItem doesn’t need to be a @State object

Comment: Also it looks like you forgot to initialize notificationManager

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you still need to initialize `selectedTaskItem`, even if its initial value is `nil`.

The good news is that `passedTaskItem` works in both cases, so you can move that initialization out of the if clause:

```swift
init(passedTaskItem: TaskItem?, initialDate: Date) {
  _selectedTaskItem = State(initialValue: passedTaskItem)

  if let taskItem = passedTaskItem {
    _name = State(initialValue: taskItem.name ?? "")
    // etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response I tried your solution but the error still persisted.  

``` 

 init(passedTaskItem: TaskItem?, initialDate: Date) {
        _selectedTaskItem = State(initialValue: passedTaskItem)
        
        if let taskItem = passedTaskItem {
            _name = State(initialValue: taskItem.name ?? "")
etc.....

```